# ASPxGridView -- How to simply add example values with only a DataSource property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datasource, devexpress, aspxgridview

Hello I have a ASPxGridView. In it(for the uninformed) is only a DataSource property for telling it what data to load. My problem is that I'm simply trying to mock up an example and don't need to tie it to an actual database. How would I do this? I basically just want a few rows and some columns but since it only takes a datasource I'm not sure how to do it. Would ObjectDataSource be what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the datasource to a list of anything like this:

```
public class Item
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Count { get; set; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  GridView1.DataSource = new Item[] { new Item { Name = "2", Count = 2 }, new Item { Name = "3", Count = 3 }, };
  GridView1.DataBind();
}


<dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="grid" ClientInstanceName="grid" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
     <Columns>
         <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Name" FieldName="Name" ReadOnly="True">
         </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
         <dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Count" FieldName="Count" ReadOnly="True" >
         </dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn>
     </Columns>
     </dxwgv:ASPxGridView>
```

Comment: Ok but the columns are not auto-generated. How do you get this method to work with thaT?

Comment: Sorry i just find out that there is a control named APSxGrid I thought you were refering to the standard asp Gridview

Comment: @alen yea it's different but actually it descends from the regular ASP.Net GridView so your advice may help. It does actually recognize the rows and such using your code(will generate 2 rows) but I can't get it to map Name and Count to columns

Comment: @alen wow ASPx stuff and you don't even know it! This did it though! It was the FieldName property that was missing from your initial code mainly. Now it works though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two other ways using DataTable:

```
    private DataTable getSampleDataSource1()
    {
        DataTable dtblResult = new DataTable();
        dtblResult.Columns.Add("Name");
        dtblResult.Columns.Add("Count");

        dtblResult.Rows.Add("Name1", "1");
        dtblResult.Rows.Add("Name2", "3");
        dtblResult.Rows.Add("Name3", "7");
        dtblResult.Rows.Add("Name4", "9");

        return dtblResult;
    }

    private DataTable getSampleDataSource2()
    {
        DataTable dtblResult = new DataTable();
        dtblResult.Columns.Add("Name");
        dtblResult.Columns.Add("Count");

        DataRow drow;
        drow = dtblResult.NewRow();
        dtblResult.Rows.Add(drow);
        drow.ItemArray = new object[] { "Name1", "1" };

        drow = dtblResult.NewRow();
        dtblResult.Rows.Add(drow);
        drow.ItemArray = new object[] { "Name2", "3" };

        drow = dtblResult.NewRow();
        dtblResult.Rows.Add(drow);
        drow.ItemArray = new object[] { "Name3", "7" };

        drow = dtblResult.NewRow();
        dtblResult.Rows.Add(drow);
        drow.ItemArray = new object[] { "Name4", "9" };

        return dtblResult;
    }

    private void setDataSource(ASPxGridView theGridView)
    {
        theGridView.KeyFieldName = "Name";
        theGridView.DataSource = getSampleDataSource1();
        theGridView.DataBind();
    }
```